# Run arbitrary app in a secure enclave (SGX)

Tags: security, sgx, enclave

I want my C++ application to launch an arbitrary app (let's say a python script through a python interpreter) inside a secure enclave (Intel SGX). Is that even possible?
The steps are the following.

1. My app initializes an enclave and performs its attestation.
2. Next, it somehow uploads a python interpreter and a python script to the enclave.
3. It also uplaods to the enclave some piece of data to be processed by the script.
4. Then, the script is being launched inside the enclave and the data is being processed.
5. Finally, the processing result is uploaded back to the host.

Is this scenario possible? If yes, are there any examples on how to do so?

Comment: While this exact scenario is not possible without a considerable amount of effort, there are solutions that allows you to partition an existing app to make it SGX-compatible. Take a look at Gramine for example.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft OpenEnclave](https://github.com/openenclave/openenclave) is also a choice.
There are many examples of adding unmodified libraries to SGX and then run the  toy applications: [oeapkman](https://github.com/openenclave/openenclave/tree/54f074b14bf8ecc2b4f4902e6d15d721fd533b8d/tests/tools/oeapkman), Package Manager and Toolbox for enclave development: [apkman](https://github.com/anakrish/apkman).

Answer (score 0):

If AWS Nitro Enclaves would satisfy you then the Oblivious framework let’s you do what you are describing.

There is a full tutorial and YouTube walkthrough of deploying FastAPI servers, as an example, [here](https://github.com/ObliviousAI/FastAPI-Enclave-Services).

*Disclosure*: I work with Oblivious but this post is in no way an ad or plug, I think it just does what @pgr is asking for.